# /etc/profile not being sourced for login shells

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

The `-l` flag to `sh` is supposed to source the contents of `/etc/profile` and other profile scripts like `~/.profile`, which generally provide the initial set of environment variables for a login session.

With that in mind, I run the command `env -i sh -l -c env` and expect to see a fresh environment plus the changes made by `/etc/profile`. However, `/etc/profile` is never sourced, despite this being the supposed behaviour of the `-l` flag. On other non-MacOS systems, this `-l` flag causes `/etc/profile` to be loaded correctly.

Why does this not work on MacOS, and how can I ensure that the profile scripts are correctly sourced in the right order as they would be on login? (Note that I do not want an interactive shell session)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other systems, `sh` is its own compiled binary as if you called `bash --posix`. From the Bash Reference Manual:

```
The POSIX startup files are executed ($ENV) rather than the normal Bash files.
```

`env -i` strips every environment variable. Even adding it back as `env -i ENV=/etc/profile` does not work.

Instead of `sh` just use `bash`:

```
env -i bash -l -c env
```